# addSubview resets the anchorPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios8, uigesturerecognizer

I'm performing panning and pinching using apple example methods to maintain the zooming where the fingers pinch. The code moves the layer anchor point where the fingers touch. Everything works fine but when I add a subview the anchor point resets and everything is out of place. 
I tried to change the subviews anchor points to match the superview ones but it comes back to the default anchor point.

Code example for pinching and the anchor point adjustment:

```
/**
Scale and rotation transforms are applied relative to the layer's anchor point
this method moves a gesture recognizer's view's anchor point between the user's 
fingers.
*/
- (void)adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UIView *piece = gestureRecognizer.view;
        CGPoint locationInView = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece];
        CGPoint locationInSuperview = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece.superview];

        piece.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(locationInView.x / piece.bounds.size.width, locationInView.y / piece.bounds.size.height);
        piece.center = locationInSuperview;
    }
}

/**
Scale the piece by the current scale.
Reset the gesture recognizer's rotation to 0 after applying so the next callback 
is a delta from the current scale.
*/
- (IBAction)scalePiece:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer scale],[gestureRecognizer scale]);
        [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];
    }
}
```

I have a self.canvasView and a self.workingView The gestures are in self.canvasView and self.workingView is a subview of self.canvasView.

Everything works fine, **but** every time I add a a subview to the self.workingView the anchor point resets and everything is out of place.

How can I avoid this behaviour? I couldn't find in the documentation that addSubview resets the anchorPoint, so I assume that I'm doing something wrong here.